# Лямбда - исчисление

Tags: математика, lambda

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот у меня вопросы к вам! 
Есть задание которые дал препод для экзамена.

1. что здесь написано я не разберу...
2. даже если и просят найти первый или второй элемент пары, то зачем делать так сложно? `fst(false, 1) = \ x y. false 1 = x = false` я решил к примеру так, через правило `fst(p,q) = (p,q)true`.
3. по каким правилам тут происходят редукции и преобразования? я не врубаюсь немножк.

Comment: @Discord, а на каком же?

Comment: @Qwertiy http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Discord, мы сейчас на русском сайте же ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy Я назвал то место, где я знаю, что можно получить ответ. Что у юзера проблемы с английским, что он экзамен завалит и далее по списку — ну вообще ни разу не мои проблемы. На этом сайте этот вопрос — оффтопик. Точка.

Comment: @Discord, лямбда-исчисление весьма близко к программированию. И поскольку русскоязычного сайта math нет, здесь вопрос вполне к месту.

Comment: @Discord, википедия: "λ-исчисление может рассматриваться как семейство прототипных языков программирования."

Comment: А код присутсвует и на фото, и во втором пункте вопроса. Вот если бы второго пункта не было, можно было бы закрывать за то, что автор ничего не делал. А так - надо оставить.

Answer (score 2):

1. Насколько я понял, написано решение задания, а ручкой внесены исправления (так как `snd = λp.p false`, а не `λp.p true`)
2. Во-первых, в λ-исчислении не введён знак `,`, не исправляйте запись на то, чем она не является: `(false 1)` это не пара `(false, 1)`, а аппликация (применение) `false` к `1`.

Ниже подробный разбор исходного задания.

Давайте разберёмся с теми сущностями, что используется в этом задании.

```
snd = λp.p false
false = λx y.y
1 = λs z.s z  # если имеется в виду число Чёрча
```

Далее выполним вычисления по стандартным правилам преобразований:

```
snd (false 1) =              # подставим snd
(λp.p false) (false 1) =     # подставим вторую скобку вместо p (β-редукция)
((false 1) false) =          # аппликация левоассоциативна, уберём лишние скобки 
false 1 false =              # подставим первое false
(λx y.y) 1 false =           # подставим 1 вместо x (β-редукция)
(λy.y) false =               # подставим false вместо y (β-редукция)
false
```

В итоге `false` является результатом вычисления.

3. Единственная операция, которая здесь использовалась, это β-редукция. Она определяет аппликацию (применение) абстракции (`λx.P`) к другому λ-терму:

   ```
   (λx.P) Q → P[x:=Q]
   ```

Где `P[x:=Q]` это замена свободной в терме `P` переменной `x` на терм `Q`.

Вы можете посмотреть основы λ-исчисления на [сайте](http://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%9B%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5).

Существуют также онлайн интерпретаторы λ-исчисления, например, [этот](https://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~gongliang13/lambda/). Важно только расставлять все скобки